# Flask-admin: different create_form and edit_form with @property in model class

Tags: flask-admin

This is my goal:

> create_form: 
>   - new_file: FileUploadField which allows my users to upload files to my webserver
>
> edit_form:
>   - new_file: FileUploadField which allows users to upload a new file to replace the existing file
>   - current_file: anchor link to download the file or text which says "No file to download"

I've decided to add a custom property to my model Instruction:

```
class Instruction(DBModel):
  gdrive_id = db.Column(db.String(64))

  @property
  def current_file(self):
    if self.gdrive_id:
      return Markup("<a href='%s'>Click here to download</a>" % \
                    url_for("instruction.download_and_send", gdrive_id=self.gdrive_id))
    else:
      return "No file uploaded."
```

And i've decided to implement this in my ModelView:

```
  form_extra_fields = {
    'new_file': form.FileUploadField(label='Instruction File',
                                     base_path=BASE_PATH, allowed_extensions=None),
  }

  form_create_rules = [
    rules.Field('new_file'),
  ]

  form_edit_rules = [
    rules.Field('new_file'),
    rules.Field('current_file'),
  ]
```

Unfortunately when I visit my edit view page I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Form  does not have field current_file

It seems like Flask-admin is not mapping the `current_file` property to the form to be rendered as HTML for the edit_form.

### How can I fix this?

**Note**
I've tried adding current_file into form_extra_fields but this does not seem to work as I have no access to the model instance at the scope of form_extra_fields

Comment: There are many ways to fix this, the most straightforward I think is to add `current_file` to `form_columns` attribute. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: @SergeyShubin if I do that then I am getting the error `relation_name = column.key AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'key'`. Looks like if it's in form_columns then FA will expect it to be a column type.

Answer (score 0):

To make it properly you need to change the appearance of file input form in flask-admin. This `FileInput` class is inherited from [`FileUploadInput`](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/form/upload.py#L33), the only significant changes are `<a href="..."></a>` added to its template and additional download parameters which are get from related field:

```py
from flask_admin.form import FileUploadInput
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
from wtforms.widgets import HTMLString, html_params

class MyFileInput(FileUploadInput):
    data_template = (
        '<div>'
        ' <a href="%(link)s">%(text)s</a>'
        ' <input type="checkbox" name="%(marker)s">Delete</input>'
        '</div>'
        '<input %(file)s>'
    )

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('id', field.id)
        kwargs.setdefault('name', field.name)

        template = self.data_template if field.data else self.empty_template

        if field.errors:
            template = self.empty_template

        if field.data and isinstance(field.data, FileStorage):
            value = field.data.filename
        else:
            value = field.data or ''

        if field.download_endpoint is not None:
            download_link = url_for(
                field.download_endpoint,
                **{field.download_attribute: value}
            )
        else:
            download_link = ''

        return HTMLString(template % {
            'link': download_link,
            'text': value,
            'file': html_params(type='file',
                                value=value,
                                **kwargs),
            'marker': '_%s-delete' % field.name
        })
```

This new `FileInput` gets `download_endpoint` and `download_attribute` attribute from related field. Inherit from `FileInputField` to define these attributes:

```py
from flask_admin.form import FileUploadField

class MyFileField(FileUploadField):
    widget = MyFileInput()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.download_endpoint = kwargs.pop('download_endpoint', None)
        self.download_attribute = kwargs.pop('download_attribute', None)
        super(FileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then override this field in your view:

```py
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class MyModelView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ['gdrive_id']
    form_overrides = {
        'gdrive_id': MyFileField
    }
    form_args = {
        'gdrive_id': {
            'base_path': BASE_PATH,
            'download_endpoint': 'instruction.download_and_send',
            'download_attribute': 'gdrive_id'
        }
    }
```